# Physical explanation of temperature dependence of chemical potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, chemical-potential, density-of-states

I have recently started my first course on statistical mechanics and have been learning about the Fermion gas.

I was calculating the temperature dependence of chemical potential for an electron gas in different dimensions and have found that the chemical potential is given by
$$\mu_{1D}=E_{F}+\alpha T^{2}+...$$
$$\mu_{2D}=E_{F}$$
$$\mu_{3D}=E_{F}-\alpha T^{2}+...$$
for some constant $\alpha$. I understand the math behind how to reach these expressions. What I want to know is the physical reasons for the behaviour. As temperature increases, the probability of the electrons occupying higher energy states increases. My understanding is that the electrons in the system may now occupy more energetic states leaving less energetic states available for us to add electrons to. This causes the chemical potential to drop as on average, the energetic cost of adding an electron to the system has gone down.

This reasoning aligns with the 3D case, but is contradictory to the 1D and 2D cases. Mathematically, the difference seems to lie with the different energy dependences of the density of states in the 3 cases, but I can't find a problem with my reasoning in the lower dimensions. Is my understanding even correct?

Thanks.